# external class to implement my interface?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

Does anyone know a way to declare an external class (part of NPM module) as a class who implements some interface?

For example:

```
import {someClass} from "someNPMmodule";

interface myInterface {
  foo: () => void
}
```

Now I want to force someClass to implement myInterface and then add foo to the prototype:

```
someClass["foo"] = function() { ... }
```

How to force someClass to implement myInterface? I want a compilation error to pop if not adding foo method to the prototype of someClass.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

```
export function foo = function() { ... };

someClass.prototype.foo = foo;

declare module 'someNPMmodule' {
    export interface someClass {
        foo: typeof foo;
    }
}
```

This code augments the module imported. It is essential that the name of the module be **identical** to the one used in the import, including paths:

I mean, if you have:

```
import { someClass } from '@author/library'
```

Then you've got to define the module as

```
declare module '@author/library';
```

Next inside the module you declare an interface with the same name as the class you want to extend and add the property definition to it. Now, outside that module declaration, you can add a new method to the prototype of `someClass` and TypeScript will recognise it.

**EDIT**:

If you have the method defined in another interface, like in your case, you can also do:

```
export interface myInterface {
  foo: () => void
}

export function foo = function() { ... };
someClass.prototype.foo = foo;

declare module 'someNPMmodule' {
    export interface someClass extends myInterface { }
}
```

Anyway, and just for the record, implementing an interface in TypeScript means just having the same properties with equivalent types, because TypeScript uses structural typing.

This means that:

```
interface A { foo: () => void }

class AImp implements A {
    foo() { console.log(''); }
}

class BImp {
    foo() { console.log(''); }
}

const arr: A[] = [];

arr.push(new AImp());
arr.push(new BImp());
```

This works, even though `BImp` does not explicitly indicate that it implements the interface. And that is because the interface just says that an object that complies with it must have a `foo` method of type `() => void`. `BImp` has such a method, and so it impliments the interface.

Similarly, in my first example, `someClass` will also implement `myInterface` just by declaring its methods.

Comment if you've got a problem with this solution.

Comment: Thank you. I know this option but I don't want to declare foo inside interface someClass. I have an interface I want to use it (myInterface) - I  want the compiler to know myClass is implementes it.

Comment: myInterface is an interface other classes are implement and I need myClass to imlemt it as well.

Comment: I modified the answer so you can directly use your interface.

Comment: Hi and thanks again, I appriciate your help and extra info. the second solution is what I tried at first, but I don't get the compilation error I want even if someClass does not have some of the methods declared under myInterface.

Comment: You can't get a compilation error for that. Remember that you're exending an existing interface, and are making a declaration, not a definition. You're just stating that `someClass` implements an interface, not defining `someClass` (which is already defined elsewhere). In the example you're saying that `someClass` has a `foo` method, and so you can use it and assign a function to that property. The compiler can't know if the method is actually defined or not. This is the closest you're going to get to you want, except if you redefine the entire library you're extending in your own project.

Comment: So there is no way to achieve this..  :/ thank you very much for all the help!